# celery the timezone not same the backend redis

Tags: redis, timezone, celery

I already set celery4.4 config timezone is "Asia/Shanghai"

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Shanghai"
```

And the terminal show now datetime.

```
2021-08-20 23:26:03,849
```

But the backend I use redis date_zone is not the same as the datetime now.

```
 "date_done": "2021-08-20T15:26:03.848352"
```

I dont know where my config is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently as documented, the resulting `date_done` isn't based on the configured Celery timezone but rather is just always UTC. That is why you are seeing 15:26 (UTC) instead of 23:26 (UTC+8).

- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.date_done
- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/internals/reference/celery.backends.database.models.html

> *property* **`date_done`**
>
> UTC date and time.

This feature has already been requested before but seems to be always de-prioritized and moved for next release. Currently, it is planned to be included in Celery 5.2.

- [The celery result column, date_done is utc, even though you set the timezone](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4948)